# RGB fade program

Tags: led

I'm working on a function to fade RGB LEDs smoothly from one color to the next, so I thought I'd use a for loop  to increment each RGB value according with the set value. I've made the for loop as following:

```
for (redFadeCurrent, greenFadeCurrent, blueFadeCurrent;
   ((redFadeCurrent != redFadeTarget)&&
   (greenFadeCurrent != greenFadeTarget)&&
   (blueFadeCurrent != blueFadeTarget));
   redFadeCurrent = redFadeCurrent + redStep,
   greenFadeCurrent = greenFadeCurrent + greenStep, 
   blueFadeCurrent = blueFadeCurrent + blueStep) {

    analogWrite(ledRedPin, redFadeCurrent);
    analogWrite(ledGreenPin, greenFadeCurrent);
    analogWrite(ledBluePin, blueFadeCurrent);
    Serial.print("Red: "); 
    Serial.print(redFadeCurrent);
    Serial.print(" Green: "); 
    Serial.print(greenFadeCurrent);
    Serial.print(" Blue: "); 
    Serial.println(blueFadeCurrent);
    delay(3000);

    if (redFadeCurrent>redFadeTarget) {
        redStep = -1;
    }
    else if (redFadeCurrent<redFadeTarget) {
        redStep = +1;
    }
    else {
        redStep = 0;
    }

    if (greenFadeCurrent>greenFadeTarget) {
        greenStep = -1;
    }
    else if (greenFadeCurrent<greenFadeTarget) {
        greenStep = +1;
    }
    else {
        greenStep = 0;
    }

    if (blueFadeCurrent>blueFadeTarget) {
        blueStep = -1;
    }
    else if (blueFadeCurrent<blueFadeTarget) {
        blueStep = +1;
    }
    else {
        blueStep = 0;
    }
```

Problem is, when one of the values hit the target the code leaves the for loop. 
I'm guessing the condition `((redFadeCurrent != redFadeTarget)&&(greenFadeCurrent != greenFadeTarget)&&(blueFadeCurrent != blueFadeTarget))` does not work.

Is there any way to work around this?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Your code sample is incomplete the end of the loop is missing `}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the problem is the condition inside the `for` statement.

Let's examine what happens when the *red* LED hits its fading target, which is, say, 100 (for the sake of the example, I will fabricate the other values):

```
for (...; (100 != 100) && (90 != 100) && (80 != 100) ; ... )
```

- (100 != 100) -> **FALSE**
- (90 != 100) -> **TRUE**
- (80 != 100) -> **TRUE**

**FALSE** && **TRUE** && **TRUE** -> **FALSE**

The condition inside the `for` evaluates to `FALSE`, therefor the loop will exit.

If you want the loop to continue as long as there is at least one LED which hasn't hit the fading target, you should change the `AND` to `OR`:

```
((redFadeCurrent != redFadeTarget) || (greenFadeCurrent != greenFadeTarget) ||
   (blueFadeCurrent != blueFadeTarget))
```

Let's examine what happens now with the same values:

```
for (...; (100!=100) || (90 != 100) || (80 != 100) ; ...)
```

- (100 != 100) -> FALSE
- (90 != 100) -> TRUE
- (80 != 100) -> TRUE

**FALSE** || **TRUE** || **TRUE** -> **TRUE** ==> The loop will continue.

And what will happen when all the colors hit the fading targets?

```
for (...; (100!=100) || (100 != 100) || (100 != 100) ; ...)
```

- (100 != 100) -> FALSE
- (100 != 100) -> FALSE
- (100 != 100) -> FALSE

**FALSE** || **FALSE** || **FALSE** -> **FALSE** ==> The loop will stop since the condition will not evaluate to `TRUE`.

Comment: ...That's kind of embarrassing!
Gotta do some exercises on my logic. :p

Thank you very much!